# Android/Java. Как в ListView в Navigation Drawer'e добавить иконки - View'ы?

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, view, android-navigation-drawer

Как в ListView в Navigation Drawer'e (стандартном) добавить иконки - TextView ImageView и пр?

[image: Рис1]

Как это делается? В каких методах пишется код добавления?

Answer (score 3):

Самый простой способ добавить иконки к пунктам в левом навигационном меню:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
        app:menu="@menu/page_left_menu"/>
```

Здесь page_left_menu это xml-файл, описывающий меню, элементы которого могут иметь свои иконки:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

      <item android:id="@+id/action_news"
            android:title="Новости"
            android:orderInCategory="1"
            app:showAsAction="never"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_news"/>
</menu>
```